# How to stop my modal from appending new rows?

Tags: javascript

**Table**

```
<table id="fisicHostsTable">
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="tableHeader">Nombre</th>
        <th class="tableHeader">IP</th>
        <th class="tableHeaders">Sistema Operativo</th>
        <th class="tableHeaders">Notas</th>
    </tr>

    <th:block th:each="fh : ${datacenterFisicHosts}">
        <div>
            <tr class="row">
                <td id="fisicHostName" th:text="${fh.name}"></td>
                <td id="fisicHostIp" th:text="${fh.ip}"></td>
                <td id="fisicHostOS" th:text="${fh.operatingSystem}"></td>
                <td id="fisicHostNotes" th:text="${fh.notes}"></td>
                <td><button class="credentialsButton" th:attr="data-fisic-host-id=${fh.id}">CREDENCIALES</button></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

**Modal:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="credentialsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Credenciales</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="credentialsTable">
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th>Usuario</th>
                        <th>Clave</th>
                        <th>Notas</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".credentialsButton").click(function(){
    var fisicHostId = $(this).data('fisic-host-id');
    $.get( "/fisicHost/" + fisicHostId + "/credentials", data => {
        console.log(data);

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var fisicHost = data[i];

            var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
            new_row.className = "row fisichost";

            var userCol = document.createElement('td');
            userCol.textContent = fisicHost["user"];
            new_row.append(userCol);

            var passwordCol = document.createElement('td');
            passwordCol.textContent = fisicHost["password"];
            new_row.append(passwordCol);

            var notesCol = document.createElement('td');
            notesCol.textContent = fisicHost["notes"];
            new_row.append(notesCol);

            $("#credentialsTable").append(new_row);
        }

        $('#credentialsModal').modal('show');

        $('#credentialsTable').remove(new_row);

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('No se pudieron cargar las credenciales.');
    });
});
```

The data array looks always like this:

[image]

the problem I have is that the credentials are repeating each time I click on the button. I want to show them once, not in a cicle but can't find the way to stop them from cycling !

I've added the remove(new_row) after the modal is showing but it's removing everything !

**EDIT:**

This is the modal:

[image]

I just want to show the first two rows cause there are two credentials I need to show, but as you can see, each time I open the modal the data is repeating itself ... i want to stop that repetition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, right before the loop `for(i=` etc, put:

```
$('#credentialsTable').empty();
```

Thus you remove all rows before adding.

So put this code just before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... could you explain a bit more? I'm pretty new to programming !

Comment: Sure, 'append' means 'add'. So you are adding rows to the table each time you're hitting the button. What you want is to replace the contents of the table at each click. Hope it's clear? Let me know!

Comment: Actually what I want to do is show the data that's comming from the data array on the modal .... but i want to show that data only once, not each time the modal is opened ... I've updated the question and added a picture to make it clearer !

Comment: Not working bro ... the new row won't exist if I put the code before the for loop !!

Comment: Right before the line for(i= etc, put:                     $('#credentialsTable').empty(); Thus you remove all rows before adding. So put this code just before the loop. Sorry, I'm on a train.

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together - Hannibal Smith, the A-team.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are retrieving credentials and adding them to the table that you have in the modal. The problem is that once you close and open model, previous data is still there and new data is being added. To avoid such situation you need to listen to modal close event and once modal is closed remove added rows.

Something like this:

```
$('#credentialsModal').bind('hide', function () {
   $('#credentialsModal tr.fisichost').remove();
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening, data is being added each time I open the modal. I want data to be shown only once, not to repeat for each time I open the modal. I've been trying with your code but I can't figure out where to put it ....

Comment: Still repeating ... I've updated the question with more info on what I need to do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery method [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.on` to only run a function the first time an event occurs.

```js
$("button").one("click", function() {
  console.log("ran only the once");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```